# Compare a variable to multiple constants

Tags: linux, bash, find, compare

I want to compare the variable NUM to numbers 1 through to 6 without having to write out a find statement for each one.

EDIT: I want to statement to be "if NUM is not equal to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 then do these things"

I tried

```
if [ "$NUM" != [1-6] ] ; then
some commands
fi
```

except that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare with a regex:

```
if [[ ! "$NUM" =~ ^[1-6]$ ]]; then
```

Comment: Note that the `[[ ]]` construct is not available in all shells; you need to make sure the script is run under bash rather than some generic brand-X shell. So, be sure to start the script with `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`. Also, there's no `!=~` operator, so if you want to negate the test (i.e. "if $NUM is NOT in 1-6), use `[[ ! "$NUM" =~ ^[1-6]$ ]]`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific when I first asked the question, but is it possible to make it so that the program enters the if loop where NUM does not equal any of those numbers?